# How to create process based log file using Log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

below are my class details. ClassA and ClassD are runnable classes. From ClassA I am calling ClassB and ClassC.

```
package comp1 -> Contains ClassA, ClassB, ClassC
package comp2 -> Contains ClassD, ClassE

Log for comp1 -> comp1.log
Log for comp2 -> comp2.log
```

I am using Log4j for logging. I have two loggers based on package name. I am calling `ClassE` and `ClassB` from `ClassD`. Now, `comp1.log` contains logging messages from `ClassB` and `comp2.log` contains log froms `ClassD` and `ClassE`.

How can I make a process based log? If I run `ClassD` there should only one log file for `ClassD`, `ClassE` and `ClassB`. Is this possible using Log4j?

Comment: Can you explain, what are the runnable classes here, what are the processes in your context, and is there any class deriving from another?

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be use System Variables.
You can write something like this in your log4j.xml

```
<appender name="ProductionLog" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="c:/logs/myLog-${myProcId}.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d] [%-5p] {%c|%t}: %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

Important is that usage of system variable **${myProcId}**
You can provide system variable for example before you initialize Log4j e.g.

```
System.setProperty("myProcId", procId);
DOMConfigurator.configure(log4jFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it, personally I would instrument the logs with extra information and then use log processing to split them back out again. If you are Linux based then this should be pretty easy and transfers the extra processing to read time rather than write time.

Ways to add extra information would be: -

- Named thread pools for each process then include that in your pattern
- [NDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/index.html) to add context specific information (this is what I use)

Another approach would be to use separate loggers which are intitialised by the constructor with a specific name (ProcessA, ProcessB). When you instantiate your dependencies you can then pass in the alternate logger name to use in the constructor or via property injection. If you are using Spring this will be easy, if not then I expect the factory pattern is your friend here.

Hope this helps.