# Create log4j logfiles per process

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm using log4j2, and have my configuration in log4j2.xml (in classpath so it s automatically configured)

In this particular case, I want to create separate log files per process.

I have a framework with multiple packages and multiple classes. They all have statements like:

```
Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass());
```

Lets say I now have three processes A, B and C. How should I configure log4j to get three output files A.log, B.log and C.log and include the logging calls made in the framework classes?

I also want to be able to log individual packages/classes to other log appenders if I need to debug etc, so I would prefer to keep the getClass() argument mentioned above.

All ideas are welcome!

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11984414/how-to-create-process-based-log-file-using-log4j

Comment: I had seen that answer actually, but I didn't fully understand it. What happens for example if the property is not defined?

Comment: What did you mean with a process? Did you mean a separate instance of JVM?

Comment: Yes, separate system processes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the desired name at the time of creating the process, adding an argument to the Java virtual machine. e.g.:

```
java -Dcustom.log.name=/tmp/logs/A.log ... ...
```

So, you can use it:

```xml
<File name="Application" fileName="${custom.log.name}">
```

See more in [*Apache Log4j 2 User's Guide*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/) [[**PDF**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-users-guide.pdf)].

Answer (score 0):

Give every process its own configuration file. Specify different paths in these configurations.

You can specify the full path of the configuration file with this system property:
`-Dlog4j.configurationFile=path/to/log4j2.xml`